# Split a String into rows and maintain mapping to other columns in R

Tags: r

Sorry if the title is a bit misleading.
Heres my problem;

I have dataframe with 3 columns

```
col1      col2      col3
Parta     3         xxx,yyy,zzz
Partb     4         aaa,bbb,ccc
```

I'd like to stringsplit col3 so that i get the contents in a new column but still maninatin the relationship to the other columns.. like this

```
col1     col2     col3
Parta    3        xxx
Parta    3        yyy
Parta    3        zzz
Partb    4        aaa
Partb    4        bbb
Partc    4        ccc
```

Simply I'm sure but I'm struggling...help appreciated..
Paul.

Comment: see `splitstackshape::cSplit()`

Comment: a duplicate of what..?

Comment: Can you give me the link to the answer..?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `separate_rows` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df1, col3)
```

Comment: can't locate tidyr{} on CRAN..?

Comment: @PaulBeales  I think the new package is library(tidyverse) which includes a dozen packages